# {I am/I will be} more than happy to be corrected

Tags: grammar

I tried to translate rather complicated nouns from my native language into English, then I wrote the following sentence:

> I referred to some online dictionaries regarding the translations. If
> anyone thinks any translation can be expressed more accurately, **I am** more than
> happy to be corrected.

Is using *I am more than happy* correct here or should I say: *I will be more than happy*?

Both make sense to me in the sentence, this why I am a little confused as to which one I should use.

I was also wondering if *don't hesitate to correct me* can be used here.
As far I know, when we say *don't* we are usually addressing a specific person or people but I am not sure if I have encountered a case in which *don't* is used to address *anyone*.

Thank you for any guidance on this.

Comment: *As far I know, when we say don't we are usually addressing a specific person or people but I am not sure if I have encountered a case in which don't is used to address anyone.* - when we use *don't* in an imperative, it doesn't matter whether we're addressing a single known person or a specific group of people or everyone in general.  For example, [a common sign says "Do not walk on the grass".](https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/dont-walk-on-the-grass-picture-id452364147)

Comment: *That's my plan. And if **you** don't like it, leave now*. That works fine with the unstated but implied subject ***you*** before the imperative ***leave now***. But If we change the *actual* (initial) instance of ***you*** to ***anyone***, the syntax seems a little "off" to me unless we change that imperative to a standard "assertion" with Subject + Verb - *if **anyone** doesn't like it, **they can** leave now* (or ***...will they** please leave now*, or similar). That's to say, the relevant factor here  is the presence of implied subject ***anyone***, not the negating ***don't***.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with you that both are mostly correct in what you are trying to say.

> I am more than happy to

means that you currently find it acceptable to do something, because it is in the present tense.

> I would be more than happy to

means that you will still find it acceptable at a later date (such as when this is read), since it is in the past tense.  Notice, here, that I changed *I will* to *I would*.  Since this structure fragment is in the past tense, using *will* is a conflict since that word is used in the present tense.

In this particular occasion, I think it would be a matter of preference and intent.  If you are verbally stating it, I would lean more towards using the present tense, but if you are making an online post, or written notice, then I would suggest using the past tense version.

I would also suggest you consider changing "If anyone thinks any translation...." to "If anyone feels that one of my translations..."

*Don't hesitate to correct me* can be used here but again this is more of a conversational thing.  You are right that it can be directed at an individual or a group of people, however.  (Also consider avoiding contractions like "don't" and use "do not" if using formal written form)  Since you have written this, you might also consider using *please feel free to send me any corrections* or *I would be more than happy to consider any corrections that you send me*."